# Arduino button press representing boolean variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, arduino, boolean

How can I make a boolean variable set to `True` in python when button pressed, so that I could have the python program execute something each time the button is pressed.

```
if button_pressed:
   print('button was pressed')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should connect the pins for button in your python script.

Maybe [this medium article](https://medium.com/@eestuffs/how-to-read-and-write-to-arduino-using-python-6d6e92c41e8) helps you out!